# Tinyduino I/O line voltage level

Tags: led, max7219

Does anyone know what the I/O line voltage level is on the Tinyduino?

[Tinyduino](https://tinycircuits.com/collections/processors/products/tinyduino-processor-board?variant=14479557959)

I want to run a MAX7219 LED array with it, like this one:

[LED Array](https://www.ebay.com/itm/MAX7219-Dot-led-matrix-MCU-control-LED-Display-module-for-Arduino-Raspberry-Pi/272583013958)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever your power supply voltage is. If you run it from 5V you get 5V IO. If you run it from a 3V coin cell you get 3V IO.

Comment: So if I want to use 5V I/O (for the Max7219) and I want portable 3.7V lithium power, then I need a boost circuit to get it to 5V?  At least that's what I take from your answer.

Comment: That's correct.